# How to extend "*" operator to a vector of strings in R that works like Python

Tags: r

In python '*' operator can works in list of strings as follows:

```
#Python code
>>> a=['a','b','c']
>>> a*2
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

But in R it does not work.

```
#R code 
> a=c('a','b','c')
> a*2
Error in a * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Althogh an answer is: use the rep function as follows

```
> rep(a,times=2)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"
```

but I want to learn how to extend an operator like '*'. I want to learn how to extend '*' operator?

Answer (score 6):

I don't really advise you to do it, but since you asked you can redefine `*` as a generic and then add your customized methods.

In this case when the first object is a character you will use `rep`, otherwise you will proceed with the normal base R multiplication as usual.

```
a <- c('a', 'b', 'c')

`*` <- function(e1, e2) UseMethod("*")
`*.character` <- function(e1, e2) rep(e1, e2)
`*.default`   <- function(e1, e2) base::`*`(e1, e2)

2*2
#> [1] 4
a*2
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"
```

Just note that with this code you can do `a*2` but not `2*a`.

Comment: if OP can afford to set a class to `x` then we might just define an S3 method. We could just set `oldClass(a) <- "character"` and then have `*.character <- function(e1, e2) rep(e1, e2)`. The cleaner way however might be to define a separate infix operator, like `%rep%`

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this utilizing `S4` class. The operator `*`, `numeric` class and `character` class are sealed. You can read more at `?isSealedMethod`.

> In the R implementation of classes and methods, it is possible to seal the definition of either a class or a method. The basic classes (numeric and other types of vectors, matrix and array data) are sealed. So also are the methods for the primitive functions on those data types. The effect is that **programmers cannot re-define the meaning of these basic data types and computations**. More precisely, for primitive functions that depend on only one data argument, methods cannot be specified for basic classes. For functions (such as the arithmetic operators) that depend on two arguments, methods can be specified if one of those arguments is a basic class, but not if both are.

However, we can define new classes that inherit these basic classes.

```r
C <- setClass("C", contains = "character")
N <- setClass("N", contains = "numeric")

setMethod("*",
    signature(e1 = "N", e2 = "C"),
    function (e1, e2) rep(e2, e1)
)

setMethod("*",
    signature(e1 = "C", e2 = "N"),
    function (e1, e2) callGeneric(e2, e1)
)

setMethod("*",
    signature(e1 = "N", e2 = "N"),
    function (e1, e2) callNextMethod()
)

setMethod("*",
    signature(e1 = "C", e2 = "C"),
    function (e1, e2) stop("illogical operation")
)
```

Test drive

```r
a <- c("a","b","c")
c1 <- C(a)
n1 <- N(2)

c1 * n1
# An object of class "C"
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"

n1 * c1
# An object of class "C"
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"

length(n1 * c1)
# [1] 6

n1 * n1
# An object of class "N"
# [1] 4

c1 * c1
# Error in c1 * c1 : illogical operation

2 * c1
# Error in 2 * c1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

2 * n1
An object of class "N"
[1] 4
```

Comment: My code above is not complete (e.g. does not address `2 * c1` and `c1 * 2`). Utilizing group generic or additional methods for `*`, you can easily fix it. I just want to focus on the `*` operator and how simple it is to implement this in `S4`.